Google notification api for groups
so i am using google users api, so for users whenever there is a change  there is https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/watch api with which i can register my url and once registered i get the events of create,delete and update. So i wanted the same thing for groups also is there an equivalent https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/watch from where i can register my url for receiving crud events of groups. thanks

You have this API https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/watch
With it you can receive all the group change events.
Remember to use "groups_enterprise" because it provides more events than "groups"
